# In Java, is it possible to use a generic interface with two type arguments as a base to subtype interfaces with one fixed type argument each?

Tags: java, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have a "base" interface:

```
public interface TargetActionDelegate<TTarget extends Target, TAction extends Action> {
    void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}
```

and the following related interfaces that fix one type argument:

```
public interface TargetDelegate<TTarget extends Target> {
    <TAction> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}

public interface ActionDelegate<TAction extends Action> {
    <TTarget> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}
```

Now it seems to me that these one-type-fixed interfaces should be supersets of the base interface, because they each handle the base case plus many others. Furthermore, since they both include the base case, they should be able to extend from the base case.

What I wanted to do was something like...

```
public interface TargetDelegate<TTarget extends Target> extends TargetActionDelegate<TTarget, ?ANYTHING? extends Action> {
    <TAction> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}

public interface ActionDelegate<TAction extends Action> extends TargetActionDelegate<?ANYTHING? extends Target, TAction> {
    <TTarget> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}
```

But I cannot find the right syntax for this OR (I think more likely at this point) I'm being really dopey about generics and Java generics in particular.

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: doh! I'm fixing that now.

Comment: This looks kinda like you're trying to force multinheritance in Java...?

Comment: Maybe, but I am not trying to... basically I want to be able to specify a specific event registrar to attach delegates for specfiic target-action combinations. Some delegates apply to just one combo, some apply to all of one target/action, and maybe some apply to all

Comment: I don't think `TargetDelegate` should extend `TargetActionDelegate`. `handle` in `TargetDelegate` is a generic method, but you want this to override a non-generic method in `TargetActionDelegate`. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I'm thinking of a situation like I have `ButtonClickDelegate` and `handle` does something specific. Then I add `ButtonDelegate` where any action, including `Click` (a subclass of `MouseRelatedAction`), does something formulaic that can encompass all actions. Then I might say `handle<Click>(myTarget, clickAction)` or `handle<MouseRelatedAction>(myTarget, clickAction)` ... I think that is roughly the scenario I have in mind... maybe I need to think it through more :)

Comment: That's the C# notation. (The `<Click>` comes before the method name in Java). The method signature `<TAction> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);` doesn't really make sense. You only need to make a method generic if the type parameter appears more than once in the signature. In this case, it should be `void handle(TTarget target, Action action)`. You should google raw types. You've managed to get this to compile by using the raw type `TargetActionDelegate` which is a really bad idea.

Comment: I'm thinking about what you said, but what about the case where I want to be able to distinguish between the method `<BaseType> handle(myTarget, subClassOfImplOfBaseType)` and `<SubClassOfImplOfBaseType> handle(myTarget, subClassOfImplOfBaseType)` ? It seems like you are saying that it is unambiguously a bad idea to try to support this, at least this way

Comment: On second thought I think I know what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is simply :

```
public interface ActionDelegate<TAction extends Action> extends TargetActionDelegate {
    <TTarget> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}
```

and

```
public interface TargetDelegate<TTarget extends Target> extends TargetActionDelegate {
    <TAction> void handle(TTarget target, TAction action);
}
```

Comment: That compiles - is there a "long" form of that type spec for the subclass so I can get a grasp of what the compiler is actually doing?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos javap -v on the compiled classes will give you a great idea of what the compiler does.